# Filtering out scanner events with logback

Tags: jetty, slf4j, logback

I am working with logback for the first time with Jetty.  I have everything working but I do have one annoying thing that I can't figure out.  Once Jetty starts, I begin to get a log file filled with these:

```
2013-03-02 11:19:23.933:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\contexts]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:24.646:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context5868271910991031759deploy]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:24.938:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\webapps]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:24.943:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\contexts]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:25.655:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context5868271910991031759deploy]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:25.948:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\webapps]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:25.952:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\contexts]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:26.665:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context5868271910991031759deploy]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:26.958:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\webapps]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:26.963:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\contexts]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:27.675:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Users\willie\AppData\Local\Temp\context5868271910991031759deploy]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:27.968:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\webapps]: {}
2013-03-02 11:19:27.973:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned [C:\Code\jetty-8\contexts]: {}
```

The syntax for the filtering in logback is a little on the cryptic side and I can't figure out how to tell logback to ignore these scan events.  I have tried the obvious

```
<filter class="oeju.Scanner" />
```

but it doesn't work.  Can anyone out there give me a little help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log format you are seeing is not logback

```
2013-03-02 11:19:26.665:DBUG:oeju.Scanner:scanned ....
```

that is the log format that Jetty's own internal [`StdErrLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/StdErrLog.html) produces.
So filtering it out with logback will not work (yet).

**How to make logback work in Jetty**

First, make sure you have the slf4j-api, and logback jars present in your server classpath.

Easiest way to accomplish this is to put them in `${jetty.home}/lib/ext/` and verify that they are present with a quick check on the command line.

```
$ java -jar start.jar --version
```

That will show you what the server classpath will have in it.

Now start jetty.  The slf4j-api classes should be detected and the internal logging switches over from [`StdErrLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/StdErrLog.html) to [`Slf4jLog`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Slf4jLog.html).

At this point you just have to configure logback. Usually with a `${jetty.home}/resources/logback.xml` file. (See [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html) for [details](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html))

**The meaning of `oeju.Scanner`**

As for the `oeju.Scanner` part, that is an abbreviated fully qualified classname that StdErrLog produces for the named logger [`org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/Scanner.html).  See how it only uses the first letter of each package namespace segment to form the `oeju`?

**How to filter Scanner events in logback**

In your logback.xml use the following, in place of what your question had, to set the logging level to INFO for that specific class.

```xml
<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner" level="info" />
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you said.  Jetty switched to using logback just as you said, its still not accepting the filter.  I will play with it a bit more and let you know.    thanks.

Comment: WOOHOO!!!!  The tag is not filter, its this <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner" level="info" />